# Best enterprise scheduler that you worked with?

Tags: scheduler

I am looking for a good scheduler that is robust across multiple platforms (windows, linux, solaris, etc) that has robust error reporting capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best one was homegrown.

Second best was Autosys.

Comment: What did you like the most about this tool?

Comment: Reasonable GUI. Homegrown tools' GUI was not as good

Comment: Why the down-vote? Someone got laid off by whoever owns Autosys these days?